# php-redis (new Redis()) getKeys() method is using "KEYS *" or "SCAN" with iterations?

Tags: php, redis, key

I am using the php-redis packages mostly available in most popular repos. The one you call as

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
```

Here if I do

```
$var = $redis->getKeys('something.*');
```

On the backend will it do the sync and blocking

```
KEYS something.*
```

Or will use scan iteratively non-blockingly allowing concurrent threads to work as

```
SCAN 0 MATCH something.* COUNT 10
SCAN $iteratorFromLastCall MATCH something.* COUNT 10
... 
while ($iteratorFromLastCall > 0);
```

Or something similar?

As the former is not supposed to be used in production and shows no issues while developing, the latter is "less guaranteed" though, but much more reliable for a high availability requirement.

Do I need to use

```
$redis->scan()
```

And iterate the cursor myself, or

```
$redis->getKeys()
```

Is already "production safe" avoiding "KEYS *"?

Comment: I think you are looking for `HSET` and `HGETALL`. https://redis.io/commands/hgetall

Comment: is HGETALL async? Or blocking the same way as "KEYS \*"? Are you sure HSET is the most optimal dataset if I use key-value storage and few times a day I search for keys through a matching pattern Like 'something.\*'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in [the source](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/blob/49b7f41d51122786cb1d754f98da331a8ca74dde/redis.c#L1207) that `getKeys()` uses the `KEYS` command:

```
/* {{{ proto array Redis::getKeys(string pattern)
 */
PHP_METHOD(Redis, getKeys)
{
    REDIS_PROCESS_KW_CMD("KEYS", redis_key_cmd, redis_mbulk_reply_raw);
}
/* }}} */
```

So you'll need to go with your second option, using `scan()` and iterating. As you say, [`KEYS` is not recommended](https://redis.io/commands/keys) for production environments:

> **Warning:** consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider using SCAN or sets.

Comment: Ah so what I'm using is PhpRedis in the end. The fact that "predis" exists confused me. Thanks, they (phpredis) even had a good code example in their doc on github for scan.

Comment: @dszakal from what I understood, you're using the PHP extension rather than a package (i.e. from composer), so you're *not* using [Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis), but [php-redis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis).